M2E in Eclipse (Maven Integration): how to see actual Maven output and customize builds?
I might be missing something fundamental here, but if I need to debug a Maven Project in Eclipse, I'm used to simply select Project -> Clean or Build Project, then look to the Errors view to find and fix all the issues and then debug. But I never saw actual Maven build output of m2eclipse (M2E), like how it downloads dependencies, compiles modules, etc. How can I see that? Also, how can I customize such a build, like by adding a custom variable or specifying custom location for settings.xml using --settings flag?
I know I can "run" a pom.xml as Maven build and specify various parameters, but doing so does not affect the errors list, i.e. it does not seem to be the same as "Project -> Clean...", so I can't debug an app that way. I also know I can chose a global/user settings.xml file from preferences, but I need a project-specific one.
I have found some info on that on the m2eclipse FAQ page, but it seems to be for running apps, not compiling. Also, it's confusing because images don't show up in that article.
FYI: I posted similar question in Eclipse Community Forums, but nobody responded for a long time, so added it here.
Thank you in advance.

At the end of the day you can always drop to the command line and do mvn compile

but if I need to debug a Maven Project in Eclipse, I'm used to simply select Project start the application/test in from your IDE in debug mode... What kind of customizing do you mean? Why do you need to specify the location of settings.xml?

@g00se, as I mentioned, doing so does not affect the errors in the Problems view and thus does not let debug. So I guess "Project -> Clean/Build" does something additional to that, which I'm trying to figure out.

@khmarbaise, the same customization that is possible when you "run" your pom.xml as Maven Build. I need to specify a custom settings.xml to make this specific project use a specific environment variable for connecting to a specific Maven Repository. Not all the projects, but just this one, thus I can't use global Maven settings under Maven -> User Settings.

So use it on the command line instead and check if the issue is Eclipse (which I assume)... put your environments into your settings.xml (why do you need configurations??) What is the purpose of that?

@khmarbaise, I need to use Eclipse to debug. If I build in command line, Eclipse does not refresh the Errors list and is unable to start the app. Although it's weird because binaries must be used from the same place... But that's what I have. In order to debug I have to do "Project -> Clean/Build" of my Maven projects first. Unless I'm missing something...

Go to the Console View and using its Open Console toolbar dropdown, open the Maven Console.


Thank you! Interesting, I did not know about such console. But it looks like it's still not the same (much less output) as I would see when running mvn compile from the terminal or "Run As Maven Build"...

Sounds like something for https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/discussions . I wonder how and why it's any different?

Thanks. As much as I hate duplicating questions, I guess I should ask it there too. If I get an answer, I will copy it here and vice versa. This includes Eclipse Community Forums.
